# Plotting vectors from dataframe using matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, vector

I have a dataframe which has X, Y, and Z columns which represents coordinates of a points (each row represents one ponint). I want to draw vector from point 1 (row 1) to point 2 (row 2). I want to repeat such thing for entire dataframe.

Here is how dataframe looks,

```
    x       y       z
0   0.67883 0.59075 0.28053
1   0.68366 0.60002 0.28022
2   0.68715 0.60797 0.27884
3   0.69358 0.61166 0.27731
4   0.70080 0.61412 0.27560
5   0.70448 0.61300 0.27581
6   0.70822 0.61747 0.27258
7   0.71459 0.62003 0.26900
8   0.71880 0.62638 0.26273
9   0.72479 0.63126 0.25372
```

The code I tried is here, it is giving mw vector but tail of the vector should be at point 1 (row 1) and head of the vector should be at point 2 (row 2) and so on.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.scatter(p[:, 0], p[:, 1], p[:, 2], color = 'r', marker = 'o', alpha = 0.5)

for i in range(0, len(p), 1):
    ax.quiver(x[i], y[i], z[i], x[i+1], y[i+1], z[i+1], length = 0.001) 

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
plt.show()
```

x, y, and z are the list containing each column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the arguments of `ax.quiver` incorrect. The first three values are the location of the arrow tail. The next 3 are the vector components, not the location of the arrow head. So you need to do some math, which can be accomplished with `.shift`.

Also, there is no need to loop, it accepts full Series or arrays.

Given your `DataFrame` named `df`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.scatter(df.x, df.y, df.z, color = 'r', marker = 'o', alpha = 0.5)

ax.quiver(*df[:-1].T.values, *(df.shift(-1)-df)[:-1].T.values , length=1)
# equivalent to
#ax.quiver(df.x[:-1], df.y[:-1], df.z[:-1], 
#          (df.x.shift(-1)-df.x)[:-1], 
#          (df.y.shift(-1)-df.y)[:-1], 
#          (df.z.shift(-1)-df.z)[:-1], length = 1) 

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
plt.show()
```

[image]